# Known contact is converting to Anonymous

Tags: fxm

I am facing below weird issues while using `FXM`

1. I can collect data from an external web form. I have utilized below
   method to save contact

```
var options = new ContactSaveOptions(true, leaseOwner);

repository.SaveContact(myContact, options);
```

Once this code gets executed then I can view the entry in Experience profile but only a contact data with Recency field null. And, there is no Visit, Profile, Goal data in the profile

After some time, I observed that contact data automatically gets null and the user becomes anonymous but now Visit, Profile, Goal data gets visible

This is happening 8 out of 10 times

2. Contact is getting `AlreadyLocked` status because of which I am not
   able to insert/ update new data.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What version of Sitecore

Comment: Its 8.1 initial version

Comment: I have checked my logs. I am getting below error
13256 13:16:07 ERROR Cannot start analytics Tracker
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.ItemNotFoundException
Message: The item "Couldn't find a profile with the ID '{B800D9B0-5518-4F12-8106-E5740F2FA795}'." was not found. It may have been deleted by another user.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.StartTracking()

Comment: Looks like you have a custom Sitecore profile in the core DB with that ID. And that profile item is not there. Search your code for that ID

Comment: I can view the profile in Experience Profile but after aggregation this profile is getting overwritten by Anonymous profile however i don't have trace or logs to confirm it.

Comment: The overwrite doesn't seem possible.